# Running groovy script in Java code

Tags: java, groovy

Hello I am looking to run a groovy script inside Java code but I didn't find many tutorial about that.

I have a String that contain a groovy script :

```
private String processingCode = "def hello_world() { println \"Hello, world!\" }";
```

I have also downloaded the Groovy SDK.

Which groovy jar should I include in java project ? And how to execute the script in Java ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need is a [`groovy-all`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.groovy%7Cgroovy-all%7C2.4.5%7Cjar) dependency and [`GroovyShell`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html).

Main class will be:

```
package lol;

import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;

public class Lol {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String processingCode = "def hello_world() { println 'Hello, world!' }; hello_world();";
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
    shell.evaluate(processingCode);
  }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/34813827) is a demo.

Use `gradle run` to run it.

Comment: There is no groovy-all in my groovy-sdk/lib directory, should I include the whole sdk ?

Comment: I guess all you need can be found under `$GROOVY_HOME/lib`.

Comment: My install has groovy-all.jar in $GROOVY_HOME/embedded

Comment: I've added the groovy-"version number".jar that is in my sdk and it worked. Thank you !